# Cursor making squares on every device

Tags: windows-8, mouse

I have an iball wireless keyboard and mouse combo. The mouse suddenly started moving against the mouse movement and finally started making square patterns on the screen. Fixes that I tried:

1. Uninstalling the drivers and rebooting
2. Disabling it and rebooting
3. Checking for any damage to the internal parts

I even tried using the mouse on other devices like my Android tablet and friends computer I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Some wireless mice repeatedly move the mouse cursor around in a square to signal that their internal battery is low.

Answer (score 1):

Using the mouse on another host and still experiencing the same issue rules out a problem with the host or drivers.

This means, its a hardware defect, and you're likely required to replace the mouse.

You can try cleaning the sensors, but it might just've been worn out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my bluetooth wireless mouse. I fixed it by removing and reinstalling the internal battery.